# How to remove a specific part of string with wildcard?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Currently, I use:

Variabls:

```
 int recordCount = 5;
 Header = "Index"; // Can also be "Starting Index"
```

Header:

```
 Header = Header.Split(' ')[0] + " (" + recordCount + ")";
```

Changes:

```
 Index (5)
```

To:

```
 Index (6)
```

When I want to replace the Header with a new Header, I use the above, but the problem is that when I start using more than one word in the `Header` it removes the rest of the Header Name. i.e. When it says `Starting Index:` it only shows `Starting`.

Can I use Regex to simply look for the value inbetween the parenthesis and replace it with another variable?

Comment: What does the initial data look like?

Comment: You are saying that the "value in between the parenthesis"  recorddCount is the dynamic value you want replaced? Or the actual value of what is index at that number?

Comment: @OmegaMan recordCount is the dynamic value I want to replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\(\w+\)");
string input = "Starting Index: (12asd)";
string replacement = "12ddsa";
string result = re.Replace(input, replacement);
```

If you need to perform more complex replacements (i.e. if the replacement depends on captured value between the braces), you'll have to stick with `Regex.Match` method

Update: with `Match` thing quickly get ugly :)

```
 Regex re = new Regex(@"^(.*)\((\w+)\)\s*$");
 string input = "Starting Index: (12)";
 var match = re.Match(input);

 string target = match.Groups[2].Value;
 //string replacement = target + "!!!!"; // general string operation
 int autoincremented = Convert.ToInt32(target) + 1; // if you want to autoincrement

 string result = String.Format("{0}: ({1})", match.Groups[1].Value, autoincremented);
```

Comment: Please note that the regex is targeted to catch and replace any alphanumeric value in braces. If there should always be a number, just replace `\w+` with `\d+`

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. Could you give me an example for `Regex.Match` too? Just so I have an idea if I decide to use that?

Comment: I gave you an example of a Regex.Match()

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for that! It sure looks like it could get complicated.

Comment: `match.Groups[2].Value` is *usually* how one would get a group's value ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace a number of these systematically (and the algorithm requires the original value), then remember that Regex.Replace() can accept a method that will return the replaced value.  Here's an example that will increment all integers enclosed in parens:

```
string s1 = "Index (5) and another (45) and still one more (17)";

string regex = @"\((\d+)\)";

string replaced = Regex.Replace(s1,regex,m => "("+(Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value)+1).ToString()+")");
// Result: Index (6) and another (46) and still one more (18)
```

The method takes a regex match object and returns a replacement string.
I used a lambda method here but your regex and the replacement method can each be as complex as needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can also go with this way:

```
string sample = "Index (5) Starting Index(0) and Length (6)";
string content = Regex.Replace(sample, @"(?<=\()\d+(?=\))", m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString());
```

This pattern will look for any number of digits wrapped with round brackets and will be advanced to 1.

Here No need to append additional brackets, since they were not captured during match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern

```
\[\((\d+)\).*?\]
```

to match the number between the parenthesis, and after that you could replace that number with whatever you want

```
var mg = Regex.Match( "Starting Index:(10)", @"\[\((\d+)\).*?\]");

if (mg.Success)
{
    var num = mg.Groups[1].Value; // num == 10
}
```

After that

```
headerString = headerString.Replace("10", "11");
```

Answer (score 0):

`\((\d+)\)` this will suits better

and will replace numbers in that case "asdq(wdq)wdqwd (12)"

Answer (score 0):

```
int dynamicNumber = 6;

string pattern = string.Format("({0})", dynamicNumber);

string data = "My Header 6:";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.Replace(data,pattern, "!!!")); // My Header !!!:
```